# Postman post to meteor server gets 502 Bad Gateway, works from iPhone

Tags: node.js, post, meteor

I'm trying to test an HTTP POST to a Meteor app running on the minimal 512MB Digital Ocean droplet.

HTTP GET works fine.  HTTP POST seemed to work when we tried it from an iPhone.  I don't own an iPhone or anything running IOS though and I want to test with Postman (or anything I can use).  Everything I run (desktop, laptop, DO server) is all Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try the HTTP POST from Postman, I get 502 Bad Gateway.  Setting up the nginx debugging at "debug level" shows the following:

```
2015/05/02 16:10:36 [error] 28431#0: *207 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.245.23.29, server: fooserver.com, request: "POST /receive HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/receive", host: "fooserver.com"
```

Comment: what does your nginx config look like?

Comment: `server {
  listen   *:80;
  server_name  fooserver.com;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/fooserver.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/fooserver.com.error.log debug;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
`

Comment: Hm, I put that in backticks, not sure why the formatting.  Also, I should mention I'm using mup to deploy, and I set it to port 3002 as a way of not stepping on another meteor app I sometimes run there.